# economy based on selling non-raw materials

Tags: phrase-request, terminology

What's the best way to describe a sector of economy that is based on selling technologies or anything else, but not on selling raw materials?

"non-raw-material economy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [three-sector model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-sector_model), you would say that it is a country whose economy is **not based on primary industry**. That, however, relies on your audience being familiar with the term. Otherwise, you could just say ***not based on the production or extraction of raw materials***. If you want to be specific, you could say ***manufacturing-based economy*** or ***service economy***.